# Can you charge 1s and 2s batteries at the same time with the tinyhawk 2 included charger?

Tags: lipo-batteries, batteries, battery-safety, tinywhoop

I just got a Tinyhawk 2. It came with 2 batteries (2s and 1s) and a battery charger that you plug in to USB.

I know that you can't parallel charge batteries with different cell count, but it looks like there is separate logic for each port on this charger.

Does anyone know if it is possible to charge both batteries at the same time? I could try it myself, but I don't like burning batteries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [source](https://brushlesswhoop.com/tinyhawk-2-review/), yes you can charge both 1s and 2s batteries at the same time. This is because, like you mentioned, there are separate charge controllers. You can also choose whether you want them to charge to 4.2v or 4.35v per cell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was really hard to find any documentation at all about this charger, and from what I have read elsewhere, I'm not alone